# How to prevent the default handler on a tr when you click on a td div span?

Tags: jquery

I have a clickable table row:

```
$("#content-display").on('click', '#myTable tbody tr', function (){           
    foo();        
});
```

The table is in the format

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><div><span></span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div><span></span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div><span></span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div><span></span></div></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When a user clicks directly in the span in the 3rd I want to call only the function `bar()` (not `foo()`)

```
$("#content-display").on('click',
                         '#myTable tbody tr td:first-child + td + td div span',
                          function (){
    bar(); 
});
```

Unfortunately, when a user clicks on that span, both `foo()` and `bar()` are called.

I tried this as well, but still both `foo()` and `bar()` are called.

```
$("#content-display").on('click',
                         '#myTable tbody tr td:first-child + td + td div span',
                          function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    bar(); 
});
```

Comment: This may help: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()` is what you are looking for.

See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `event.preventDefault();` try using:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Updated handler:

```
$("#content-display").on('click',
                     '#myTable tbody tr td:first-child + td + td div span',
                      function (event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    bar(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can stop it from triggering the first event with `event.stopPropagation()`